# How do I fix Ionic 6 exit code 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-native

I get this error when connecting to a firebase. The version I'm using is ionic 6.
https://ibb.co/FbDp9zs

Comment: Its only when you connect database ?

Comment: As the error message says you need to update to Angular 13. Did you try to update to Angular 13?